# Should the form used for "editing" a record always echo the fields which were in the form used for "adding" the same record?

Tags: forms, edit, mental-models

I am designing a form for editing some employee records of an attendance marking system. In the system, when a manager is adding an employee, he has to assign the employee to a workgroup.

Later when editing the same employee, I thought not to include the workgroup selector because managing workgroups are done in a separate view.

I made the workgroup selector available in the "add employee" form to make the "add employee" flow easier for manager because then it reduces the risk of manager forgetting to add the new employee to a workgroup.

I assumed that manager will be navigating to workgroup section directly and do the task when he/she wants to remove or add an **existing** employee to another group.

So the questions I have regarding this are:

since we had the workgroup selector in "Add employee" form, will the users expect to edit workgroups at the "edit employee" form too?

Will the user's mental model be interrupted by having workgroup selector separated from the edit employee form?

Is there any conventions about echoing the same fields in edit mode which were available in add ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes users' mental models expect to edit workgroup on the Edit Employee page!**

I would ask:

Why not to have the Edit Workgroup on the Edit Employee page? Does it increase the cognitive load? Is it a secondary action to the Edit Employee page? **If No, then just have it on the Edit Employee page.**

If your answer is **Yes**, you still can provide the Edit Workgroup option as a secondary action by providing a link that would either:

- Expand the view and display the fields to edit the workgroups.
- Or display an Edit Workgroup pop-up, user makes the workgroup selection, close the pop-up, then save.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYAzAn.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

*- *Either way, I would still provide users the ability to change Employees Workgroups from the Edit Employee page.*

Comment: Cannot keep the Edit Workgroup on the Edit Employee page because there's a different section for workgroup and I am using a popup for edit emp and yes it's a secondary action. However, as you mentioned I managed to accommodate an option for user to edit workgroup and edit emp. details from the same "Employee details" screen by using popups. Thanks for giving the insight on it. Image of final design: [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IxbGnz5bQp-RgGozjcpQEir-M4ILfVnn)

Comment: @NadeekaAthukorala Nice. At least the user is able to edit the profile and workgroups from the employee details page, which is good.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 'Change Workgroup' is a frequently used feature, it makes absolute sense to have it separated from the Edit Employee form. However, the CTA for 'Change Workgroup' should be prominent so as to not keep the user guessing. As a good practice for forms, displaying less fields is better in order to reduce cognitive load, faster completion and keeping the user focussed on answering what is required.